# Error "Filter Failed" Printing on Brother HL1202 with ipp/http on server cups with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, 64-bit, arm, brother

I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Server 20.04 and I can't print remotely at least in Ubuntu. The server works fine in Windows and after many attempts I came to the conclusion that the problem is cups.

I read in articles that the "Filter Failed" error in many cases was fixed changing the driver on some printers and I tried without results. I tested both PPD's provided by the Brother official page driver (https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=mx&lang=es&prod=hl1200_us_as) and other one provided by the package "printer-driver-brlaser "from Ubuntu repository and both give different errors. The first  let's call it "HL1200.ppd" it's succefull to send the file without problems to the server and it responds that the printing was completed but this does not really happen. The second one "br1200.ppd" which seems to be more recent gives the "Filter Failed" error mentioned before.

For a long time I thought that the problem was with the arm version and so I started to trying between computers amd64 with ubuntu 20.04 giving the same result but after much experimenting I remember on ubuntu 18.04 I can print previously where I have successful now. I tried to use the source code of one older version but this one needing more dependencies among other problems and I gave up.

I can print perfectly in ubuntu ever the printer is connected via usb except on arm if I printed with HL1200.ppd but the remote printing problem even persists when trying to print from the web server creating a new printer via loopback (127.0.0.1). What I mean by this is I create one printer with cups which is connected via usb which is shared and another which is connected to the previous one via http/ipp all this on the same machine therefore it is not a network problem and this persists both in arm64 and amd64 . I also tried changing the rastertobrlaser file located in /usr/lib/cups/ from ubuntu 20.04 to the another one from 18.04 with not success.

I haven't a problem putting files to the server manually and printing it via cli. I need to be able to print quickly and know that server is available for everyone.
I hope you will excuse me for my bad English and for the excess of words but I wanted to clarify as much information as possible. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem.

I managed to solve it thanks to the ppd provided by Ubuntu version of raspberry pi(arm64). Trying to print from another raspberry pi I couldn't add the printer so I tried it with lpadmin but I needed the ppd, so I got it when the printer was added automatically (however it can't print for some reason when adding it this way manner). This file is located in "/etc/cups/ppd/"printerfile.ppd"(In my case "/etc/cups/ppd/HL1200.ppd"). However, I checked the file obtained by the client machine and this differs slightly from the one found on the server machine. Once added with the instructions: lpadmin -p "printer-name" -E -v device -P "full path to ppd"(In my case "lpadmin -p HL1200 -E -v http://192.168.XX/printers/HL1200 -P "/home/user/Desktop/HL1200.ppd"), using the recently acquired ppd file the print works perfectly, it even works on the Lubuntu 20.04 AMD64 version which was the source of the problem.

How recommendation if you have a similar problem, a temporary solution is to print with an android device, no drivers are needed, it works instantly and smoothly.